# Why does a silly patent like this and others exist?

Tags: us1130741

In reference to the patent: [US1130741](https://www.google.com/patents/US1130741)

Comment: There is nothing silly about this patent. You do realize it's over 100 years old.

Comment: Please share your exact problem and what types of problems you faced. I am not understand what you want. Please explain it.

Comment: The fundamental "reason" for patents (like this) is that the inventor discloses his contribution to increasing the state of the art in exchange for the right to prevent others from financially benefiting from it, without a license, for a limited time.  In this case, that time is long gone.

Comment: It seems silly now because the language is old fashioned, and the technology now seems trivial.  At the time, it was an advancement in pencil technology.